# How can i archive every 2 files in a folder with 7zip

Tags: zip, archive, 7zip, winrar, winzip

How can i archive every 2 files in a folder with 7zip. I want 7zip to take the name of the first file for the archive. Is it possible.

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but only with a split rar file (files with extensions like part1.zip , part2.zip etc.  )  If the files were not splitted then extract them in a single folder with a name that you want for archive and then create archive by splitting the folder in 2 parts . Next time whenever you will extract them , they will be extracted in a single folder having the name of first folder